# Operation is not supported c#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, codedom, .net-4.8

im using codedom library to compile some codes in string format.
i have to use this library in a .net core project.
first i made a project with .net framework(because codedom works with .net framework) , and every thing worked fine. but when i refrenced my .net core project to the first project i faced with "Operation is not supported" in first project.
`CompilerResults compileResult = codeCompiler.CompileAssemblyFromSource(compileParams,
code);`

what should i do to fix this?
thanks for your time.

Comment: The fix is simply to not use CodeDOM. It's not supported on Core (up to and including .NET 6). The alternative is to use Roslyn to compile code, or a library dedicated to parsing specific expression formats rather than arbitrary C# (which is dangerous to begin with).

Comment: Take a look into https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting